# How to logout from a webpage implemented in jsp - JavaEE and NetBeans

Tags: jsp, http-status-code-404, web-inf

I am trying to develop a JavaEE 7.0 web application using NetBeans (IDE), GlassFish 4.1.0 (web server) and MySql 5.7.11 (Database server). My Operating System is Windows 8.1.

I would like to implement a very basic authentication system. The user enters a username and a password already inserted in the database and if it is correct, he will be able to access a webpage called patient.jsp. He is also able to log out from this webpage.Therefore, I proceeded in the following way in order to develop this authentication system:

1- I created three files patient.jsp,loginform.jsp and PatientServlet.java. This is the project hierarchy:

[image: Project Hierarchy]

2 - The code is:

For **PatientServlet.java**:

```
@WebServlet("/patient")
public class PatientServlet extends HttpServlet {    
private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

    @override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/patient.jsp").forward(request,response);
     }
  }
```

For **loginform.jsp**:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    Sign In:
    <form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
        Username:<br>
        <input type="text" name="j_username" size="20">
        Password:<br>
        <input type="password" name="j_password" size="20">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
    </form>
</body>
```

For **logout.jsp**:

```
<%@ page session="true"%>

User '<%=request.getRemoteUser()%>' has been logged out.
<% session.invalidate(); %>

<br/><br/>
<a href="test">Go to Log In form </a>
```

For **patient.jsp**:

```
 <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
 <%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>

  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
     <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       <h1>Hello!</h1>
       <a href="logout.jsp">Click here to log out </a>        
      </body>
   </html>
```

3- Therefore, I executed the application and I started the LogIn Form as desired:

[image: LogIn form]

4- Then, I obtained the following webpage as wished:

[image: LogIn success]

5- However, when I press the LogOut link, the following error appears:

[image: Error webpage]

I really do not know what is going on. Could you help me please ?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logout.jsp is not directly accessible from the client since it is located in the WEB-INF directory. You need to move logout.jsp to the root of the web application.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much Mark for your answer !